# Why does 1...1 evaluate to 10.1?

Tags: php, echo, ellipsis

I've just faced a little PHP snippet from 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/jmrZB

```
echo 1...1; //10.1
```

And I'm afraid I have no idea how to explain its results. Why is this considered valid at all?

Comment: Note: the SO syntax highlighter makes the first dot red, while the others are black. This is a nice hint, I think. It would be nice if the last dot were red, too, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: From nearly 3 months ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/684l1p/11_is_101/

Comment: tricky concatenation issue...

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The dot (`.`) has two roles in PHP:

1. As decimal digit, when it is part of a real number, e.g. `1.1`. Both the integral part and the decimal part are optional on real numbers **but not on the same time**. This means both `1.` and `.1` are valid real numbers in PHP but `.` is not a number.
2. As the [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). This operator connects two string sub-expressions into a larger expression. The value of the larger expression is the concatenation of the string values of the sub-expressions. The sub-expressions that are not strings are converted to strings before concatenation.
   E.g. `1 . 1` is the same as `'1' . '1'` and its value is the string `'11'`.

The expression `1...1` is parsed as `1. . .1`. According to those said above, `1.` and `.1` are real numbers (`1.0` and `0.1`) and the middle dot (`.`) is the string concatenation operator.

When converts numbers to strings, PHP uses the minimum amount of characters required for this operation. If a real number has only integral part then it represents the number as integer, without decimal point and decimals.

This is why `1. . .1` is the same as `'1' . '0.1'` and the final value of the expression is `10.1`.

#### Why is `1...1` parsed this way?

The parser reads the expression from left to right. `1` tells it a number starts there. `1.` is a valid real number but `1..` is not. It keeps `1.` as a number then the next dot is the concatenation operator. The next `.`, being followed by a digit, is the beginning of another real number (`.1`).

All in all, `1...1` is the same as `1. . .1`.

Comment: I just tried `echo 1/.1`, it resulted in `10`. How come it still concatenated the two integer even with just one `.`?

Comment: @Swellar `1/.1` is `divide 1 by 0.1` which is 10.

Comment: `1/.1` is a number. It is `1` divided by `0.1`. The value of expression `1/.1` is `10`. There is no string involved.

Comment: @axiac That makes sense, thank you. I just tried some things after reading this question.

Comment: When we write it like this "1. . .1" (with spaces between middle dots) - then it makes things clear.

Comment: The parser reads the expression from left to right. `1` tells it a number starts there, `1.` is a valid real number, `1..` is not; it keeps `1.` as a number then the next dot is the concatenation operator; the next `.`, being followed by a digit, is the beginning of another real number (`.1`).

Comment: Assuming that this answer is correct, why does neither `1..1` nor `1..1.` print "**11**"?

Comment: The parser is greedy. It reads as much as it can while the fragment still makes a valid token. This is why `1.` is a float number and not the integer `1` followed by the concatenation operator (`.`). For the same reason, `1..1` is `1.` followed by `.1` and `1..1.` is `1.` followed by `.1` followed by `.`.

Answer (score 61):

Because it's interpreted as `1.` `.` `.1` (`1` and `0.1`) therefore you get `10.1`

Comment: Uhm, I thought ... was the splat operator, nice work

Comment: The . is a concatenation operation not a plus.

Comment: Seems to make sense, but PHP does not concatenate numbers using dot in general, but here for some reason it does.

Comment: php does what you tell it. Here you tell it `concatenate` items. As items are not string - php converts'em to strings.

Comment: There is no such thing as *"concatenating numbers"*. Strings are concatenated; the numbers are first converted to strings before concatenation.

Comment: When we write it like this "1. . .1" (with spaces between middle dots) - then it makes things clear. That's why I was surprised, because we do not have spaces in the source.

Comment: @DamienPirsy It is in other contexts, but it wouldn't make any sense to have a splat operator _right after another value_...

Answer (score 45):

Applying braces will make it clear:

`(1.) . (.1)`

- `1.` is interpreted as `1`
- `.` is string *concatenation*
- `.1` is interpreted as `0.1`

This all put into a string is `10.1` *as a string*.

`var_dump(1...1)` yields`string(4) "10.1"`

Comment: Applying braces is only clear if you already know where to apply them though.

Comment: @pipe Thats why I have shown *how* to apply them.

Answer (score 22):

Different Operations.

```
1. <?php echo 1.1; ?> // gives simple 1.1
2. <?php echo 1...1; ?> // gives 10.1
3. <?php echo 1..'1'; ?> // gives 11
4. <?php var_dump(1.); ?> // gives 1
5. <?php var_dump(.1); ?> // gives 0.1
```

Now, our strange operation

```
echo 1...1
```

is treated as concatenation of no 4 and no 5, resulting in 10.1